# How to make character array in string array?

Tags: java

The array example:

```
String wordList[] = {"pig", "dog", "cat", "fish", "bird"}
```

I have transform Str to Char , Half Width to Full Width and UpperCase.
look like

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++){
char cha = str.charAt(i);
cha = Character.toUpperCase(cha);
cha += 65248;
System.out.print(cha);
}
```

So, I have a question about how to make a new array such as {'p', 'i', 'g'};

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

Comment: Have a look at the `toCharArray()` method. That does what you need. You can use that with an enhanced `for` loop to iterate over your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will print `[ＰＩＧ, ＤＯＧ, ＣＡＴ, ＦＩＳＨ, ＢＩＲＤ]`

```
String[] words = new String[]{"pig", "dog", "cat", "fish", "bird"};
char[][] charWords = new char[words.length][];

for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
    String str = words[j];
    char[] chars = new char[str.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char cha = str.charAt(i);
        cha = Character.toUpperCase(cha);
        cha += 65248;
        chars[i] = cha;
    }

    charWords[j] = chars;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.stream(charWords).map(String::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be usefull

```
for (String str : wordList){
   char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
   System.out.println(charArray.toString());
}
```